# Well Locations in NAD27 do not overlay well locations on aerial or satellite images, i.e. Google Earth

Tags: geolocation

Well Locations in NAD27 do not overlay well locations on aerial or satellite images, i.e. Google Earth.  Computations are based on accurate locations and would like to know if it is better to place symbols for well location on Google Earth and re-compute lat/lon coordinates or use the raw data as supplied.

Comment: Have you tried reprojecting your Well Locations? Which CRS did you choose, and what was the result?

Comment: How accurately were they surveyed?

Comment: Another consideration, I'm not sure what kind of well you're talking about, but with directional/horizontal drilling, oil and natural gas wells can have the "well location" be accurate but no where near the surface well pad site if the data is supposed to represent the base of the well.  I don't know if this is relevant to your data or not, so feel free to ignore, but passing along in case it is.